# vue/ has no exported member 'toRefs' when use tsx

Tags: typescript, vue.js

when i import 'toRefs' from 'vue' in tsx script , the tslint give me 'has no experted member toRefs' error, even i can find this funtion's declare in ts file.

**export declare function toRefs(object: T): ToRefs;**

here is code

```
<script lang="tsx">
import { defineComponent, toRefs } from "vue";
import { Column } from "./VueTableColumn.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    // ...
  },
  setup: (props, { emit }) => {
    const { pageNo, pageSize, rowClass, dataList, rowStyle, columns } = toRefs(props);
    return () => (
      // ...
    );
  },
});
</script>
```

here is error

```
ERROR in src/components/VueTableBody.vue:2:27
TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member 'toRefs'.
    1 | <script lang="tsx">
  > 2 | import { defineComponent, toRefs } from "vue";
      |                           ^^^^^^
    3 | import { Column } from "./VueTableColumn.vue";
    4 |
    5 | export default defineComponent({
```

here is my package.json file , did i use the wrong package version?

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.4",
    "ant-design-vue": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "element-plus": "^1.0.2-beta.54",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-v5": "^0.0.1-security",
    "sass": "^1.32.13",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0",
    "ztree": "^3.5.24"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-loader-v16": "^16.0.0-beta.5.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "@vue/standard",
      "@vue/typescript/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
}
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question and . Nothing that you posted requires to be an image. In addition, there's not enough details. This shouldn't happen under normal circumstances because this export exists in Vue 3. Make sure you use correct Vue version

Comment: Ok, I edit my quesion, I dont think it's  the Vue verion problem, thanks anyway

Comment: I didn't notice the mention of tslint. The problem is totally different then and you need to accent this, the problem is totally specific to it, not to Vue or Typescript. A compiler, IDE and linters are all different tools and handle TS and Vue SFC differently. It may work with one tool and not work with another. As for tslint, it's obsolete and may have its own quirks which aren't widely known because it's eslint with ts plugin that is currently widely used (and also in this setup). Any way, you need ask the question about a linter. In case you really use tslint, switching to eslint may help

Comment: By your opinion, i fix my problem by change typescript version. It looks like the conflict between Vue and TS version. Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, i fixed my problem by change typescript version.

From

```
"typescript": "~3.9.3"
```

To

```
"typescript": "^4.3.5"
```